# Finding Theta Notation in terms of n

Tags: notation, big-o

Find a Θ notation in terms of n for the number of times the statement `x = x + 1` is executed in the segment below:

```
i = 1
while (i < n^2)
    x = x + 1
    i = 3i
```

I know that `i` has a growth rate of `O(3^k)`, but I am not sure how to get `Θ` notation in terms of `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out, given `n`, how many times can you perform `i = 3*i`, starting from `i = 1` before `i >= n^2`. You already know that after `k` steps, `i = 3^k`, so your task is solving

```
3^(k-1) < n^2 <= 3^k
```

, that is, write `k` as a function of `n`.

Comment: So doing that, I look at n^2 <= 3^k. If I take the log of both sides, I get k = log base 2 of n. So that would give me a Θ(logn). Right?

Comment: You've lost a couple of constants, but for the Θ that doesn't matter.